# Mac keystroke problems with Synergy PC server

Tags: ubuntu, mac, keyboard, hotkeys, synergy

I'm running Synergy server 1.4.13 on Ubuntu (PC) and have a connected Mac client.

It works well, except some keys like Home and End (defined as hotkeys in ~/.synergy.conf for the Mac client) do not work on the Mac.

I found an options section for ~/.synergy.conf which will send special keystrokes to the Mac when <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> is hit on the PC server, but an unfortunate side-effect is that <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> do not work at all on the PC when configured this way.

What's more, is even when the Mac screen is not the active screen, it *still* gets the <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys sent to it. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I think this is the same as bug `#190`. It is still preset on revision `1800` as reported by `hm.sh revision` http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/190/

Comment: Also added a fix to wake up the screen when the mouse moves to the mac display. Synergy doesn't handle this by default so you have to push the button on the back of the display to wake up the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead an made a patch for this.

I haven't tested for more than a couple hours but it seems to be working with my PC server and Mac clieint.

I tried to get some help to understand the source code on #synergy IRC but nobody seems interested in talking so here it is [patch](https://github.com/joesuperuser/synergy).

Apply with `patch --ignore-whitespace -p0 -i joes.patch`.

Then the usual `./hm.sh conf -g1; ./hm.sh build`.

On the mac client, I wasn't able to build using the hm.sh script. I had to build with `./hm.sh conf -g1 --mac-sdk 10.8; make`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my PC server and Mac client.

It was easier to change the mac's behavior by creating a file at ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

```
{
"\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                   /* Home         */
"\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";                         /* End          */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + End  */
}
```

A reboot is needed for the mapping to take effect.